# How do I incorporate input validation in this code?

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement input validation into this program but it keeps coming out wrong. I tried using another while statement but it didn't work. It normally pops up with the text which shouldn't be. I want it to show after the person inputs the wrong information. I want it so that if the data entered is invalid, they will have to re enter it.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
/*
1. Declare variables for month 1, 2, and 3.
2. Declare variable for Total and Average Rainfall
3. Ask user to input name of months.
4. Then ask user to input inches of rain fall.
5. Add all inches and then divide by number of inches asked. In this case, 3.
6. Display average inches of rain for all months to user.
*/

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
 string month1, month2, month3;//Declared values for months aswell as total and average rainfall. 
 double month1Inch, month2Inch, month3Inch;
 double averageInches;
 double totalInches; 
 char c = 'y';

 do
{

    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;
    cout << "Enter first month's name:";
    cin >> month1;
    cout << "Enter rain inches for " << month1 << ":";
    cin >> month1Inch;

    cout << "\n";

    cout << "Enter second month's name:";
    cin >> month2;
    cout << "Enter rain inches for " << month2 << ":";
    cin >> month2Inch;

    cout << "\n";

    cout << "Enter third month's name:";
    cin >> month3;
    cout << "Enter rain inches for " << month3 << ":";
    cin >> month3Inch;

    cout << "\n";

    totalInches = (month1Inch + month2Inch + month3Inch);
    averageInches = (totalInches) / 3;//calculating the average

    //Display calculated data.
    cout << "The average rainfall for " << month1 << ", " << month2 << ", " << "and " << month3 << " is " << averageInches << endl;

    cout << "Would you like to recalculate? Either enter Y to run or N to not." << endl;
    cin >> c;


} while (c == 'Y'||c=='y');

if (c != 'Y' || c != 'y')
    cout << "you must enter the correct choice" << endl;

system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

I tried putting an if statement under     "cout << "Would you like to recalculate? Either enter Y to   run or N to not." << endl;
        cin >> c;"  but i get an infinite loops.

I am not getting any error codes. Just the text showing up with "would you like to recalculate?" line and infinite loops.

Even when I input the data with that showing, I get an infinite loop somewhere. So I deleted it.

Comment: So you ended up showing us the code which doesn't even attempt to do what you want and asking us to write it for you. SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and get rid of all those redundant comments in `main()`.

Comment: @Anton Savin, I added the code I had earlier again.

Comment: The code currently posted works fine as far as I can tell, except for the system("pause"). At least it does what I expect from looking at the code.

Comment: Is it the Y/N response that you're trying to validate?  It seems like you're doing it too late, as you're checking it after the do-while loop has completed.  Also, which compiler (and version) are you using?  Some older compilers require you to flush the output stream before trying to read the input (otherwise the display order is scrambled), but this shouldn't be an issue in newer compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to validate the Yes or No response.  That requires a loop that exits only when you have an acceptable input.  It's separate from the loop that decides if the calculation should be run again.

```
int main() {
  // ...
  do {
    // ...

    do {
      cout << "Would you like to recalculate? Either enter Y to run or N to not." << endl;
      cin >> c;
    } while (c != 'Y' && c != 'y' && c != 'N' && c != 'n');
  } while (c == 'Y'|| c=='y');

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```